# nconf not loading file synchronously

Tags: node.js, nconf

Trying to use `nconf` to load a file into memory and use that for configuration. However, every time I call `nconf.get` it returns undefined leading me to believe I'm being dealt an async function. The path I'm using seems correct.

I noticed the `FileStore` has a `loadSync` method but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: I don't know which exact nconf module you're using, but [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nconf) says that: **All calls to .get(), .set(), .clear(), .reset() methods are synchronous since we are only dealing with an in-memory object.**.

Comment: I'll check the paths again, but I figured I might check since the documentation is fairly incomplete.